# Check if MediaElement has a Source

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

When using a `MediaElement`'s `SetSource` method, the media `MediaElement`'s `Source` remains `null`. So how do we check if it has a source, that is, how do we check if `Play` will actually play something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if `MediaElement` has a valid `Source`, we can take advantage of [**MediaElement.MediaOpened event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened.aspx). This event occurs when the media stream has been validated and opened, and the file headers have been read. So if this event occurs, it must be able to actually play something.

Besides this event, we can also check [**MediaElement.CurrentState property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.currentstate.aspx), this property returns the current state of this [**MediaElement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx). The state can be one of the following (as defined in the [**MediaElementState**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.mediaelementstate.aspx) enumeration): **Buffering**, **Closed**, **Opening**, **Paused**, **Playing**, or **Stopped**. The default value is **Closed**. And **Closed** represents the [**MediaElement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) contains no media. So while the current state is closed, It means there is no source and if the state is not closed, it should be able to play something.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `MediaOpened` event `MediaElement` has also `MediaFailed` event which is raised when selected source can't be opened